# Cuda kernel to calculate column mean of 2d array

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, cuda

I want to create a kernel that adds the means of the columns of two 5x5 2d arrays to a third 1d array.

Logic:

```
for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
{
    float suma = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        suma += a[i][j] + b[i][j];

    c[j] = suma / N;    
    cout<<c[j]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Using a column-summing loop like this does not require a 2 dimensional grid. 
 Therefore you should spin up a 1D grid and your thread check should be `if (col < 5)`.  You only need 5 threads for this.  You can get rid of the `int row = ...` line. 
 Instead of this: `sum += a[col*5+i] + b[col*5+i]` (which is missing a semicolon) try this: `sum += a[i*5+col] + b[i*5+col];`.  And shouldn't `c[row] = ...` be `c[col] = ...` ?  If that doesn't fix it, then you may have some other problem with your code or CUDA setup, and should at least provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, I applied the changes you provided, but now it seems to me like it only adds the first rows of both arrays. How could iterate the other rows also?

Comment: You may have a problem elsewhere in your code.  A kernel, by itself, is not a [mcve].  What you have shown so far is not a [mcve]

Comment: Yes the problem was with malloc and memset so i tweaked them and now it works as intended, thank you very much for the help

Comment: @StavrosSpiridis consider answering your own question or deleting it for future reference

Answer (score 1):

Cuda Kernel that calculates (1,)=mean((:,))+mean((:,)):

```
 __global__ void meanKernel(float *c,float *a, float *b)
{
   int col = blockIdx.x* blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   float sum = 0;
   if (col<N)
   {

       for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        sum += a[i*5+col] + b[i*5+col];


       c[col] = sum/5;
       }
      }

 }
```